# Error "no se encuentra el tipo de datos DATE" al ejecutar la consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en sql server y tengo que poner un campo con la variable DATE pero cuando corro el query me manda este error:

`Columna, parámetro o variable nº 9: no se encuentra el tipo de datos DATE.`

Comment: Qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?, el tipo de datos `DATE` existe desde SQL Server 2008

Comment: @Lamak estoy usando la v17.3 que es la mas nueva

Comment: v17.3 suena a que me contestaste sobre la versión de SQL Server Management Studio, que es simplemente el software con el cual te conectas al motor de bases de datos. Estoy preguntando por la versión de SQL Server que estás usando en el servidor: `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: @Lamak muchas gracias si era la version del SQL SERVER

Comment: Hola, fijate que te arreglé algunos errores y traté de mejorar un poco la claridad del título. Que siempre debe tratar de indicar de qué se trata tu problema de una forma breve y concisa. Puede que tu problema tenga que ver, como dijo Lamak, con la versión del software que estás usando, así que trata de agregar la mayor cantidad de información sobre el sistema en el que estás trabajando para que te podamos ayudar.